# Suckerfish CSS menu not expanding for submenu

Tags: css, joomla, suckerfish

My suckefish menu on site http://www.lendorlaw.com cut off the right side of my menu.  when you hover over practice areas it cuts of the word LAW.  Some assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the width of the `li` is smaller that the `a`

suckerfish css...
`#navmenu li li { width: 173px; }` Remove/Override this...

`a` = `width: 250px;`

Comment: +1 since Carla doesn't seem to understand the importance of marking as answer.